# Why & how spray nozzle turns liquid in small droplets

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I just want to know that how spray nozzle turns liquid in small droplets. This thing does not only happens with spray it also happens with perfume bottle or when you squeeze a very high pressure pipe. If you know the answer to it then please share it with me.

Comment: [It's complicated](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/aerosolcans.html).

Answer (score 1):

turning liquid into spray happens this way:

In the case of a garden hose with a nozzle on its end: The water gets shot out into the air at significant speed. The water stream then encounters resistance from the air it passes through, which tends to break the solid stream of water up into separate blobs of water which pull themselves into spheres. This process slows down the jet to the point where the air can no longer break up the blobs any further.

In the case of water being forced out of a fine needle tip, the water forms a single uniform jet that persists until random perturbations cause capillary waves to form on the surface of the jet, and it smoothly fragments into individual droplets of remarkably uniform size.

In the case of a perfume atomizer, the movement of air through a venturi restriction creates a low pressure zone within the venturi, and if there is a small pipe full of fluid leading into the venturi, the low pressure will draw liquid out of the pipe and break up the resulting stream of liquid into a cloud of very small droplets.